# What are the people talking about?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

I play *Roller Coaster Tycoon 1* occasionally - It's still lots of fun. :)

However, every time I play, I hear the people saying stuff like *"Dora Dora Dora!"*, *"SpongeBob"*, and *"Looney Tunes"*. Has anyone else heard this or am I crazy? Is this what they're actually saying?

I'm not even sure those shows were around when this game was made, except for Looney Tunes.

Comment: Yes, I've heard it to. It's also in RTC2 and (I believe) RTC3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you're not crazy. ;-)

They really say sentences like that. They even say some noise sentences but some key-/ buzzwords are really clean to hear - like your "Looney Tunes".